# Toggle button slider with multi state. Left and Right

Tags: android, slidetoggle, togglebutton, android-sliding

I'm was implementing a slider like thing in my application. I came across an app from the play store, they used `ToggleButton` or `Drag Drop` feature from android, I'm not sure. The layout looks like this:

[image: Toggle button or drag drop]

In this the blue circle in the middle can be slide left or right according to the user. Here is the image of sliding circle.

[image: Sliding middle button]

Accordingly some action will be done for the user.

Please help me in understanding this implementation. Is this `custom toggle button` or something else?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using customized seekbar.